# Is it possible to modify the DOM before the page is sent to the printer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have a print.css that is applied to the document when they print. Is it possible to modify the DOM (reposition elements) before the page is actually sent to the printer?

Or can I modify the DOM, once its modified print the document via javascript print().

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way to achieve this is to use a [print media stylesheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

You can then modify the dom via css within a stylesheet when the document is rendered for print.

In what way do you want to modify the dom that you cannot achieve using this method?

Comment: So I have a grid layout using tables, and I would like so that when they print, to stack each quadrant o the table on top of each other so that its more readable.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

One trick I have used is to insert a hidden Iframe into the page and copy only the content I want printed into it, then call `window.print()` from the Iframe.

Comment: How does that go if the user initiates printing from the keyboard or browser menu?